# saving php result in different table

Tags: php

I have a page that can display a result using fetch array. Because I added a field `NINS-LEC` column to my page, I'm having a hard time saving it from another database table. How can I solve this problem?

```
<html>
<head>   
</head>
<body>
<?php
$server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
$db =  mysql_select_db("bsswebtool",$server);
$query = mysql_query("select * from soa where InvoiceAccNum  in 
('7000068191',
'7000068205',
'7000068060',
'7000068094',
'7000068078',
'7000068086',
'7000068311',
'7000068019',
'7000068299')");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    ?>
    <table class="striped">
        <tr class="header">
            <td>Groupings</td>
            <td>InvoiceAccNum</td>
            <td>AccountFirstName</td>
            <td>SubsidiaryCode</td>
            <td>HandlingCode</td>

        </tr>
        <?php
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".'NINS_LEC'."</td>"; //change group name
               echo "<td>".$row['InvoiceAccNum']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['AccountFirstName']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['SubsidiaryCode']."</td>";
               echo "<td>".$row['HandlingCode']."</td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }
        ?>
    </table>
       <?echo "$num_rows Rows\n";?>
 <? echo 
"<fieldset>
<table width='680'><tr>
<td colspan='4' align='center'>
<input type='submit' name='btn_save' value='Save'>
</td></tr></table></fieldset></form>";
}?>

</body>
```

This is my code for saving it to new table
 $query_insert_outbound = "INSERT INTO NINS_LEC (rid,invoiceno,grouping,Address,Subscribercode,AccountTitle,AccountFirstName,InvoiceAccNum,InvoiceNumber,HandlingCode,SubsidiaryCode,LastBillBal,CurrentCharges,TotalDueAmt,Rental_othrC,VatTag,UsageTag,OctTag,BalanceCarryFwd,PaymentReceived,Adjustments,Current,Over30days,Over60days,Over90days,Over120Days,CreditLimit,WithoutTaxTag,InvoiceCurrency,ExchangeRate,AsOnDate)
            values('','$invoiceno',
                 '$grouping',
                 '$Address' ,
                  '$Subscribercode',
                  '$AccountTitle',
                  '$AccountFirstName',
                  '$InvoiceAccNum',
                  '$InvoiceNumber',
                  '$HandlingCode',
                  '$SubsidiaryCode',
                 '$LastBillBal ',
                 '$CurrentCharges',
                 '$TotalDueAmt',
                 '$Rental_othrC',
                    '$VatTag',
                    '$UsageTag',
                 '$OctTag',
                 '$BalanceCarryFwd',
                 '$PaymentReceived',
                 '$Adjustments',
                 '$Current',
                 '$Over30days',
                 '$Over60days',
                 '$Over90days',
                 '$Over120Days',
                 '$CreditLimit',
                 '$WithoutTaxTag',
                 '$InvoiceCurrency',
                 '$ExchangeRate',
                 '$AsOnDate' )";

```
    mysql_select_db("bsswebtool",$server);  
    $server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");            
    $insert_query_query =mysql_query($query_insert_outbound) or die(mysql_error());
   $insert_rows_affected= mysql_num_rows($insert_query_query);
//echo $query_insert_outbound;?>
```

This only my sample code that fetch data from table query. I need to save my result to other table thanks .

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. It seems that you're trying to include some additional data from another table, but although you have constructed a query you're not actually requesting the data from the database. I suggest you post the database schema and clarify your requirement.

Comment: What do you mean: "getting hard time on saving it"?

Comment: i mean i'm having hard time how can i save data result from other table.. i just add save button but i dont know how can i create php script that will save query result including NINS_LEC since i just add it to my code.

Comment: If you want to send data you need to first learn how to fill a form correctly. Your data are outside the `<form>` tags and thus useless. Only to view, not for sending to a .php file where you can update. So ask a question how to set up a <form ... > ... </form> correct.

Comment: sorry if i add form tag i just copy does code and try to play on it..

Comment: Now please tell us you have a `table A`  where you can get data with or without `NINS_LEC` . 2.) You have a emtpy `table B` where you want to write to, the same data , like a copy ? OR 3.) you have a hard time saving it from another database table ! Have you now saved the data or not ?? Tell us correct. The name of the tables how many tables you have where they differ . Tell us in more than one sentence, what do you want to do. What have you tried and what does not work.

Comment: @user2797566, We expect u to study the basics before questioing here.

Comment: @user2797566 : your `insert` code works now, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, you this already that to save from, you need to declare the fields in the form. A form post would expect to have form fields to be presented which, in your case, is not happening as you are just displaying the data in the table. May be you can take the following approach (note that I've changed the TD elements to form elements:

```
<html>
<head>   
</head>
<body>
<?php
$server = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
$db =  mysql_select_db("bsswebtool",$server);
$query = mysql_query("select * from soa where InvoiceAccNum  in 
('7000068191',
'7000068205',
'7000068060',
'7000068094',
'7000068078',
'7000068086',
'7000068311',
'7000068019',
'7000068299')");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    ?>
    <form name="vw_ob_save" method="post">
    <table class="striped">
        <tr class="header">
            <td>Groupings</td>
            <td>InvoiceAccNum</td>
            <td>AccountFirstName</td>
            <td>SubsidiaryCode</td>
            <td>HandlingCode</td>

        </tr>
        <?php
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
               echo "<tr>";
               echo "<td>".'NINS_LEC'."</td>"; //change group name
               echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"invoice_num\" value=\"". stripslashes($row['InvoiceAccNum']) ."\" /></td>";
               echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"first_name\" value=\"". stripslashes($row['AccountFirstName']) . "\" /></td>";
               echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"subs_code\" value=\"". stripslashes($row['SubsidiaryCode']) ."\" /></td>";
               echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"handling_code\" value=\"" . stripslashes($row['HandlingCode']) . "\" /></td>";
               echo "</tr>";
           }
        ?>
    </table>
       <?echo "$num_rows Rows\n";?>
 <? echo 
<table width='680'><tr>
<td colspan='4' align='center'>
<input type='submit' name='btn_save' value='Save'>
</td></tr></table>
</form>";
}?>

</body>
```

Let me know if you need further assistance on this.

Comment: As I understand, OP want's to save data without a form.

Comment: @user2797566 : To me, you said, as I pointed out that your data is outside the <form> tags  : `you want no <form ...>...</form>` ???

Comment: @anupam : Now OP has the next problem how to fill the new created data field `NINS-LEC` with data . Your answer did not answer the main point .

Comment: @moskito-x: OP can always mark my solution as "unanswered". As his question is not clear enough, I provided him just a way to save the form. If you know the solution, please provide. Thank you :)

Comment: @anupam : Look at the updated question : The asker has no knowledge base. He wants we write code for his problems and that's what you did. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you guys i already did it, sorry i was confused and looking for immediate answer